# Organizing values of child elements for processing of a draggable form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

in my form, the user can click a button to create input fields.  Inside each of the created input fields, they can click the "add media links" button to create another input field underneath.  They can add as many media links as they please or none at all. The first set of input fields are also sortable. I have the user interface working, I'm just wondering how to go about processing it.

right now, I am basically grabbing all of the values entered from the first set of input fields (aka "thestepvalues" in the code) and then grabbing all of the values entered from the second set of input values (aka "links" in the code) and then URL enconding it and serializing it to send to the my process.php file.  The code is below:

```
$("#new_post").submit(function(e){  
    e.preventDefault();  

    //enter each of the values for 'the step' input field into an array
    var thestepvalues = $("input[name='thestep\\[\\]']")
          .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();

    //enter each of the values for each 'links' input field into an array     
    var linkvalues = $("input[name='link\\[\\]']")
          .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();

     //this will basically convert everything entered into the steps as well as the links fields
     //into URL appropriate strings to pass on to the process.php file
    var i, string="";
    for(i=0;i<thestepvalues.length; i++){
        string += "thesteps[]=" + encodeURI(thestepvalues[i]) + "&";        
    }

    for(i=0;i<linkvalues.length; i++){
        string += "links[]=" + encodeURI(linkvalues[i]) + "&";      
    }


    //send the data from the string (both kinds of input fields) as well as any
    //other input fields (that aren't dynamic) from the form
    $.post("process.php",  string + $("#new_post").serialize(),
    function(data){
        if(data.email_check == 'invalid'){

                $("#message_post").html("<div class='errorMessage'>Sorry " + data.name + ", " + data.email + " is NOT a valid e-mail address. Try again.</div>");
        } else {
            $("#message_post").html("<div class='successMessage'>" + data.email + " is a valid e-mail address. Thank you, " + data.name + ".</div>");
            }
    }, "json");    
});
```

For a sample of data entered into the form, how do I go about indicating which link belongs to the parent input field?  Baring in mind the parent input fields are sortable jquery ui elements.

here's a sample set of data entered, as you can tell I have no way of knowing which input field the child links belong to:

```
[thesteps] => Array
    (
        [0] => This is really the second input field, but dragged up to the first position.
        [1] => This is the second input field, but used to be in the first position.
        [2] => this is the third input field
    )

[links] => Array
    (
        [0] => this is the first (child) link for the first position.
        [1] => this is actually the (child) link for the third field!
    )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance

-- 24x7

Comment: is there anything I can add to clarify my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use HTML5 custom data attributes, setting the value of each linked set to be the same number.

For example:

```
<input id="1" data-newinput-id="1" />
<input id="2" data-newinput-id="1" />

<input id="3" data-newinput-id="2" />
<input id="4" data-newinput-id="2" />
```

Even if the inputs are re-arranged, you can match them up by getting the attribute values in jQuery like so:

```
var id = $(this).attr("data-newinput-id"); // 1
```

Comment: 3 weeks ago, I read this post and have spent this past bit implementing this solution you have brought fourth.  Thank you sincerely, the project I am working on would not have been possible without this key suggestion. I wouldn't know what else I would have done without this.  Thank you so much once again.